# How to convert List of JSON Objects to JSON Array using Java EE?

Tags: javascript, java, json

I am trying to convert some JSON objects to a JSON Array. I am fetching the data from a mysql database. My current code is using this loop:

Main Class:

```
    public class Main 
    {
        ResultSet resultSet=null;
        TestDAO testDAO = new TestDAO();

        public List<JSONObject> getJsonObject()
        {
            resultSet = testDAO.getResultSet();
            List<JSONObject> resList = JsonServices.getFormattedResult(resultSet);
            return resList;
        }

        public JSONArray getJsonArray() throws Exception {
            resultSet = testDAO.getResultSet();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                    obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1).toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
                }
              jsonArray.put(obj);
            }
            return jsonArray;
        }


        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
        {
            Main m = new Main();
            List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
            JSONArray jArr = m.getJsonArray();

            for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(jArr.get(i));
            }



        /*for(int i=0;i<jObj.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(jObj.get(i));
        }*/
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
public class JsonServices 
{
    public static List<JSONObject> getFormattedResult(ResultSet rs)
    {
        List<JSONObject> resList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        try
        {
            ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCnt = rsMeta.getColumnCount();
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=1;i<=columnCnt;i++)
            {
                columnNames.add(rsMeta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase());
            }
            while(rs.next())
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for (int i=1;i<=columnCnt;i++)
                {
                    String key = columnNames.get(i-1);
                    String value = rs.getString(i);
                    obj.put(key, value);
                }
                resList.add(obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                rs.close();             
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resList;
    }

}
```

My current loop returns data in this format:

```
{"fineloadinmetric":"648265.32","waterlevel":"45.59","fdate":"2017-08-29","discharge":"43391.657","runinthousand":"156.771","courseloadinmetric":"50538.462","mediumloadinmetric":"176808.134","floodflag":"false"}
{"fineloadinmetric":"856793.621","waterlevel":"44.94","fdate":"2017-08-28","discharge":"46843.674","runinthousand":"212.579","courseloadinmetric":"43957.152","mediumloadinmetric":"132528.51","floodflag":"false"}
{"fineloadinmetric":"898789.111","waterlevel":"45.66","fdate":"2017-08-27","discharge":"43436.507","runinthousand":"159.727","courseloadinmetric":"53053.74","mediumloadinmetric":"169307.45","floodflag":"false"}
```

I need the JSON array like:

```
[{
        name: 'fineloadinmetric',
        data: [648265.32, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'waterlevel',
        data: [45.59, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'fdate',
        data: [2017-08-29, 2017-08-28, 2017-08-27, 2017-08-26, 2017-08-25, 2017-08-24, 2017-08-23, 2017-08-22]
    }, {
        name: 'discharge',
        data: [43391.657, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'runinthousand',
        data: [156.771, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }, {
        name: 'courseloadinmetric',
        data: [50538.462, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }, {
        name: 'mediumloadinmetric',
        data: [176808.134, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }, {
        name: 'floodflag',
        data: [false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true]
    }]
```

Please ignore the data, it's from a different sample.
I will be using this JSON Array to geenrate some charts using Highcharts.js.

Comment: By the comments to my answer, I presume the Service class wasn't necessary for the question, so I put in an edit suggestion to remove it. Also, if my answer or someone else's solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted with the checkmark icon under the vote buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the sort of objects you want to return, I'd first populate a `Map<String,JSONArray>` with the "data" arrays. So iterate over the output you currently get with this

```
Map<String,JSONArray> map=new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++){
  JSONObject object=(JSONObject)jArr.get(i);
  for(Iterator<String> it=object.keys();it.hasNext();){
    String key=it.next();
    if(!map.containsKey(key)){//This initializes the array on first element
      map.put(key, new JSONArray());
    }
    //This fetches the array corresponding to the member's name from the map
    JSONArray array=map.get(key);
    //put the member's value into the array
    array.put(object.get(key));
  }
}
```

Now, `map`'s entry set looks pretty much like the desired output you posted. The only thing left to do is to convert that entry set into a `JSONArray`

To do this, get `map`'s entry set with `map.entrySet()`, which returns a `Set<Entry<String,JSONArray>`, which you can iterate over with a for-each loop. Calling an entry's `getKey()` returns the `String` the element maps, which goes into `name` in a `JSONObject` like the ones you say you want. Calling the entry's `getValue()` returns the `JSONArray` built by the loop, which goes into `data`. Add these objects to a `JSONArray` and you have what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @spaul I added some more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the variable currentResult used for here?

Comment: `currentResult`is the end product that you're currently getting, which I think is the `jArr` in main. I'm pretty sure you can't really use for-each on that, though.

Comment: You are right. My end product right now is a json array but JSON Array is non-iterable. So I'm getting an error when using jArr in place of currentResult. Also, I haven't initialized any Maps yet.

Comment: @spaul it seems you need to use the old fashioned for-loop syntax and declare `JSONObject object=jArr.get(i)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help again but I cant instantiate the map object since it's an Interface. I had to override all the functions. Also, the put() function's parameters are (String Key, JSONArray Value). So, I'm getting another error.

Comment: I went ahead and threw in the map instantiation to the code. Java's Collection implementations are kind of a pain in the neck to learn.

Comment: Yes, I'm just beginning to learn collection framework myself. Also, the put()  function's parameters are (String Key, JSONArray Value). So, I'm getting another error since I'm just passing the json array only in map.put(new JSONArray()).

Comment: @spaul Fixed that.